# SQLAlchemy ORM add Session Sleeping and not Committing on SQL Server 2022

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm, pyodbc

I'm following [SQLAlchemy ORM's Quick Start tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html) and can't get the first code to work on our company's SQL Server 2022 database. I'm able to create tables (and commit them), but I'm unable to commit after adding the data. The script doesn't do anything after the insert statements. No commit is performed.

To troubleshoot and perform some further testing, I've setup my own SQL Server database (using AWS RDS). To my surprise, the exact same code from the tutorial (with a different connection string, of course) works without any problems.
I've, therefore, reached out to our DBAs, and they see the session sleeping without performing a commit.

Here's my Python code (which is copy+pasted from the SQLAlchemy ORM Quick Start):

```py
from typing import List
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

import engine_creator


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    fullname: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    addresses: Mapped[List["Address"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email_address: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_account.id"))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="addresses")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = engine_creator.create_engine(echo=True, future=True)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:
        spongebob = User(
            name="spongebob",
            fullname="Spongebob Squarepants",
            addresses=[Address(email_address="spongebob@sqlalchemy.org")],
        )
        sandy = User(
            name="sandy",
            fullname="Sandy Cheeks",
            addresses=[
                Address(email_address="sandy@sqlalchemy.org"),
                Address(email_address="sandy@squirrelpower.org"),
            ],
        )
        patrick = User(name="patrick", fullname="Patrick Star")
        session.add_all([spongebob, sandy, patrick])
        session.commit()
```

Running this code on my own database executes successfully with the following debug output:

```
/Users/thomasv/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_orm/venv/bin/python /Users/thomasv/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_orm/src/main_tutorial.py 
2023-09-11 13:27:53,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
2023-09-11 13:27:53,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-11 13:27:53,156 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT schema_name()
2023-09-11 13:27:53,157 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00025s] ()
2023-09-11 13:27:53,315 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST('test max support' AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:27:53,316 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00029s] ()
2023-09-11 13:27:53,368 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT 1 FROM fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default)
2023-09-11 13:27:53,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00031s] ()
2023-09-11 13:27:53,472 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-11 13:27:53,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:27:53,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00031s] ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'user_account', 'dbo')
2023-09-11 13:27:53,586 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:27:53,586 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.1096s ago] ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'address', 'dbo')
2023-09-11 13:27:53,696 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-09-11 13:27:53,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-11 13:27:53,755 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.id AS id__1 SELECT p0, p1 FROM (VALUES (?, ?, 0), (?, ?, 1), (?, ?, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, p1, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter
2023-09-11 13:27:53,755 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00010s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('spongebob', 'Spongebob Squarepants', 'sandy', 'Sandy Cheeks', 'patrick', 'Patrick Star')
2023-09-11 13:27:53,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO address (email_address, user_id) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.id AS id__1 SELECT p0, p1 FROM (VALUES (?, ?, 0), (?, ?, 1), (?, ?, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, p1, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter
2023-09-11 13:27:53,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00008s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('spongebob@sqlalchemy.org', 4, 'sandy@sqlalchemy.org', 5, 'sandy@squirrelpower.org', 5)
2023-09-11 13:27:53,970 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I run this exact same script using our company's SQL Server database, I get the following output:

```
/Users/thomasv/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_orm/venv/bin/python /Users/thomasv/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_orm/src/main_tutorial.py 
2023-09-11 13:29:31,059 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
2023-09-11 13:29:31,059 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-11 13:29:31,095 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT schema_name()
2023-09-11 13:29:31,095 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00027s] ()
2023-09-11 13:29:31,215 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST('test max support' AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:29:31,215 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00042s] ()
2023-09-11 13:29:31,251 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT 1 FROM fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default)
2023-09-11 13:29:31,251 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00030s] ()
2023-09-11 13:29:31,322 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-11 13:29:31,327 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:29:31,327 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00040s] ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'user_account', 'dbo')
2023-09-11 13:29:31,384 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
2023-09-11 13:29:31,384 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.05768s ago] ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'address', 'dbo')
2023-09-11 13:29:31,442 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-09-11 13:29:31,481 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-11 13:29:31,483 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.id AS id__1 SELECT p0, p1 FROM (VALUES (?, ?, 0), (?, ?, 1), (?, ?, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, p1, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter
2023-09-11 13:29:31,483 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00014s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('spongebob', 'Spongebob Squarepants', 'sandy', 'Sandy Cheeks', 'patrick', 'Patrick Star')
2023-09-11 13:29:31,742 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-11 13:29:31,744 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO address (email_address, user_id) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.id AS id__1 SELECT p0, p1 FROM (VALUES (?, ?, 0), (?, ?, 1), (?, ?, 2)) AS imp_sen(p0, p1, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter
2023-09-11 13:29:31,745 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00021s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('spongebob@sqlalchemy.org', 4, 'sandy@sqlalchemy.org', 5, 'sandy@squirrelpower.org', 5)
```

As you can see, there is no `COMMIT` after the `INSERT INTO` statements. However, there is a `COMMIT` after the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the tables are correctly created.
Our team doesn't manage the database, and our DBAs can't determine the problem. They have been able to determine that the session is sleeping.

Can anyone point me in the direction of things I can attempt or I can ask my DBAs to look into (in terms of SQL Server configuration)?

Thank you for any help you can offer!